# XNA 2D Tile Collision Code Efficiency

Tags: c#, xna

I'm created a game in xna, and I've searched and searched for a good way to get collision detection.  If the player is colliding with a tile on top, it should stop moving down.  If the player is trying to move to the right and there's a tile there, don't let it move.  Vice-versa for moving to the left.  I haven't really found anything good, but I did come up with something of my own.  Can anyone tell me if this is a good way to do collision detection or is there some other easy way to do it?

```
public static class Collision
{
   //Test to see if rect1 is colliding with rect2 on top
   public static bool gravColliding(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
   {
        if (rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Top && rect1.Top < rect2.Top && ((rect1.Left < rect2.Left && rect1.Right < rect2.Right && rect1.Right > rect2.Left && rect1.Bottom < rect2.Bottom) || (rect1.Right > rect2.Right && rect1.Left > rect2.Left && rect1.Left < rect2.Right && rect1.Bottom < rect2.Bottom) || (rect1.Left >= rect2.Left && rect1.Right <= rect2.Right) || (rect1.Left <= rect2.Left && rect1.Right >= rect2.Right)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Test to see if the right side of rect1 is colliding with rect2
    public static bool rightSideCollide(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
    { 
        if ((rect1.Right >= rect2.Left && rect1.Left < rect2.Left && ((rect1.Top >= rect2.Top && rect1.Bottom <= rect2.Bottom) || (rect1.Top <= rect2.Top && rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Bottom) || (rect1.Top >= rect2.Top && rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Top && rect1.Top <= rect2.Bottom) || (rect1.Top <= rect2.Top && rect1.Bottom <= rect2.Bottom && rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Top))) && !(gravColliding(rect1, rect2)))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    //Test to see if the left side of rect1 is colliding with rect2
    public static bool leftSideCollide(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
    {
        if ((rect1.Left <= rect2.Right && rect1.Right > rect2.Right && ((rect1.Top >= rect2.Top && rect1.Bottom <= rect2.Bottom) || (rect1.Top <= rect2.Top && rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Bottom) || (rect1.Top >= rect2.Top && rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Top && rect1.Top <= rect2.Bottom) || (rect1.Top <= rect2.Top && rect1.Bottom <= rect2.Bottom && rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Top))) && !(gravColliding(rect1, rect2)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I tested this and it works, but I don't know if it's efficient- and I know being a good programmer is not just about getting things to work, but making it efficient.  Don't make fun if I did it a really long and unefficient way, I'm still learning.  Thanks, help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Err.. [rect.Intersect(rect2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464123.aspx)? I don't see why you're making all those checks yourself. Just check if he's colliding with a blocking tile, and stop him if so.

Comment: I need to know if he's colliding with certain side, because if he's colliding with the top of a tile, he should stop falling.  The problem is that if he's colliding with the side, he'll stop falling as well because the engine will recognize this as a collision.

Answer (score 0):

the rectangle.intersects(rectangle) is way better and to check eash side you just make four offset rectangle away from main rectangle and check if they intersect with another rectangles

Comment: Please clarify this answer and adding a code sample wouldn't hurt either.